# Injecting spring beans into a groovy script

Tags: spring, groovy

Is it possible to inject Spring beans into a groovy script?

I want to be able to use service/repository methods from a spring application in groovy scripts

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to inject Spring beans into a groovy script?

Yes.  You can "inject" any object you like, Spring Bean or otherwise, into a Groovy script.  It isn't injection in the sense that Spring does dependency injection, but you can get the variable into the script easily by putting it in a shell binding:

```
    def binding = new Binding()
    
    // instead of "new"-ing up an instance, you could do this
    // from wherever in your Spring app that you have injected
    // the SomeHelper bean
    binding.someHelper = new SomeHelper()
    
    // script could be loaded from a file, or hardcoded,
    // loaded from a db, etc...
    def groovyScript = '''
        println someHelper.magicNumber
    '''

    def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
    shell.evaluate(groovyScript)
```